# count values in one dataframe in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, intersect

Assume I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  D = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
  Q = c('asd', 'reg', 'rt'),
  id = I(list(c(124, 532, 78), c(1, 3, 532), c(2, 3, 78, 124, 1)))
)
```

and another one like this:

```
clusters <- data.frame(
 g = I(list(c(124, 78, 1),c(2, 3, 89),c(532, 533)))
)
```

I want to count the times the elements in each id list are in the groups g1, g2, g3 (each row in clusters) when it's more than once. So basically count the intersection whenever the intersection > 1.

The output should be:

```
out <- data.frame(
  D = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
  Q = c('asd', 'reg', 'rt'),
  id = I(list(c(124, 532, 78), c(1, 3, 532), c(2,3,78, 124, 1))),
  count = c(2, 0, 5)
)
```

I cannot do it with for loop cause it will take forever as I have 70k rows.

A for loop would look like this:

```
for row in df:
  for group in clusters:
     if group intersect row$id > 1
        count=count+intersection
  count=0
```

Comment: Your `clusters` frame is an error, you cannot have 2 elements in `g3` and 3 elements in the other columns. Also, your `df$id` changes between your initial definition and the expected output, is this process supposed to filter/change the contents of `df$id`?

Comment: So, sorry for this. I have corrected it. I was trying to make a minimal example set.

Comment: I _really_ appreciate the effort, realize it can be frustrating helping when there are errors just creating the sample data ... are the errors in the real dataset or just "here"? You might hear some confusion now that you no longer have `g1`, `g2`, and `g3` in your sample `clusters`.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a row-wise comparison between `df` and `clusters`, or is it effectively `unlist(clusters)`?

Comment: For each row in df I want to see how many people (id column) are in the clusters. If there is at least more than 1 person in the same cluster I want to count how many.

Comment: More clearly, are you comparing the 1st row in `df` to the first row in `clusters`, then the 2nd rows, then the 3rd rows? Or do you want to compare 1st row of `df` to all rows of `clusters`, then 2nd row in `df` to all rows of `clusters`, etc? And if it is the "all rows of `clusters`" option, then do you need to keep track of which cluster it came from or just add them all up?

Comment: So for example the first one is 2 because 127 and 78 are in cluster 1 and the intersection between row and cluster 1 > 1.

Comment: No, I'm not doing 1-1, 2-2, 3-3 comparison. I'm doing 1-vs-all, 2-vs-all, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can try base R

```
transform(
    df,
    count = rowSums(outer(id, clusters$g, \(...) mapply(\(...) {
        l <- length(intersect(...))
        l * (l > 1)
    }, ...)))
)
```

or `dplyr`

```
df %>%
    left_join(df %>%
        unnest(id) %>%
        left_join(clusters %>%
            mutate(grp = row_number()) %>%
            unnest(g), by = join_by(id == g)) %>%
        summarise(count = {
            d <- table(grp)
            sum(d[d > 1])
        }, .by = c(D, Q)))
```

which gives

```
  D   Q           id count
1 A asd 124, 532, 78     2
2 B reg    1, 3, 532     0
3 C  rt 2, 3, 78....     5
```

Comment: I should get 2, 0, 5.

2 because 78 and 124 are in cluster 1 and the intersection is 2. 532 doesn't count since intersection with cluster 3 is only one. And I want the intersection to be > 1.

Comment: the second row I get zero since the intersection with the clusters is never > 1.

Comment: why do you get 5?

Comment: because 78, 124, 1 are in cluster 1. And the intersection is > 1, so add the intersection (3) and it becomes 3.  Then 2, 3 are in cluster 2 and the intersection is > 1, I add the intersection (2) and it now becomes 5.

Comment: Okay, then I'm going to infer that your second `df$id` is wrong, since it is only length-3, it can never count to 5

Comment: dplyr version is much faster! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's no way around some bespoke code.

```r
sapply(df$id, function(id1) {
  lens <- sapply(clusters$g, function(z) length(intersect(z, id1)))
  sum(replace(lens, lens == 1, 0))
})
# [1] 2 0 5
```

---

```r
df <- structure(list(D = c("A", "B", "C"), Q = c("asd", "reg", "rt"), id = structure(list(c(124, 532, 78), c(1, 3, 532), c(2, 3, 78, 124, 1)), class = "AsIs")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `tidyverse` solution, but you're probably better off using `base` solutions provided for performance.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  unnest(id) %>% 
  left_join({clusters %>% 
      rownames_to_column("r") %>% 
      unnest(g)}, by = c("id" = "g")) %>% 
  add_count(D, Q, r) %>% 
  summarise(id = list(id), n = first(n * (n > 1)), .by = c(D, Q, r)) %>% 
  summarise(id = list(unlist(id)), count = sum(n) , .by = c(D, Q)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

#>   D   Q               id count
#> 1 A asd     124, 78, 532     2
#> 2 B reg        1, 3, 532     0
#> 3 C  rt 2, 3, 78, 124, 1     5
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>